# How to anchor an SVG line to the bottom of a variable height container?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm attempting to run a line on the borders of a div container and I'm getting slightly confused.

If I was placing a div along the edge, I would use:

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px;">hello world</div>
```

But the only SVG code that I can get to work seems incorrect:

```css
#BorderContainer805  {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 99%;
 height: 150px;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 0;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #696969;
 border-style: solid;
}

#HorizontalLine1118  {
 position: absolute;
 stroke: rgba(154,154,154,1);
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

#HGroup811  {
 position: absolute;
 top: 43px;
 right: 20px;
 min-width: 20px;
 min-height: 20px;
 overflow: visible;
 text-align: left;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
}

#Hyperlink812  {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-top: -0.2em;
}

#Image817  {
 position: absolute;
 display: table;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="BorderContainer805">
 <svg style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><line id="HorizontalLine1118" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="100" y2="100"></line></svg>
 <img id="Image817" height="60" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-icon.png?v=93426798a1d4">
 <div id="HGroup811">
  <a id="Hyperlink812">Home</a>
  <a id="Hyperlink813">Services</a>
  <a id="Hyperlink814">Products</a>
  <a id="Hyperlink815">About Us</a>
  <a id="Hyperlink816">Contact Us</a>
  <span style='display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 0; vertical-align: middle;'></span>
 </div>
</div >
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're trying to use SVG for this. Wouldn't `border-bottom` CSS on the div be more efficient?

Comment: In a simple case one would use border bottom but I'm working on a tool where you can add lines to a div. And some cases cannot be solved by border. For example, let's say you wanted 5 lines along the bottom with widths of 100 and of various heights (ie a column chart).

Comment: Why does your code seem incorrect? It seems to work as far as I can tell.

Comment: It isn't anchored to the bottom of the container. It's position is explicitly set to the 100px. I'll change the height of the container and show the borders and you can see the line is not anchored.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. Try `style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;height:1px;width:100%"`. I think you need to define a height in order to position it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just one change: instead of  `"height: 100%"` on the `<svg>` element, use `"top: 100%"`

```html
<svg style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 100%; bottom: 0; top: 100%">
  <line id="HorizontalLine1118" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="0" y2="0"></line>
</svg>
```